# Some blockchain start ups are proposing streaming money (getting your salary every second). Technically speaking, how does this work?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

Links of startups:
https://www.superfluid.finance/home
https://sablier.finance/

From my understanding, every financial transaction is recorded in the blockchain and it is technologically expensive to do so. Hence, why is it feasible to transact every single second?

Comment: superfluid mentioned this in their documentation. but what does this actually do behind the scenes? -> What's a Super Token? It's just a "wrapped" or upgraded ERC20 token. This is what enables the cool super-powers like streaming, batch calls, and more.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are different blockchain platforms in addition to the public Ethereum, and some of them can provide, under certain conditions, a transaction execution time of the order of 1-2 seconds. These are mainly platforms for building private networks: Quorum, Hyperledger Fabric, Corda.
2. Fast solutions are built on the basis of a high-speed data payment channel, the state of which is periodically anchored into the blockchain. At the same time, the transactions themselves are not laid out on the blockchain - for example, Lightning Network for bitcoin.